# Play framework localisation is not working in production

Tags: scala, playframework, localization

If I run my play framework application with "play run" the localisation is fine. But if I do a "play dist" then use the start command, then the original English messages appear.
I have found, that if I change the classpath order in the start script putting the jar containing my messages file to the first place, then the localisation is fine.
Is there any better way to do this?

It is the same, if I copy the conf/messages to conf/messages.hu and set application.langs="hu" in the application.conf.
And stays the same, if I change my browser settings, so this is in the request header: "Accept-Language:hu,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6". Still English messages (only, if they are the built in keys. My custom keys are translated correctly).

Answer (score 1):

We have figured it out.

There is a [custom field constructor](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors) used. My assumption was, that it is using the **implicit lang** parameter, but this is not the case. The lang must be given to the elements.errors() as parameter, and the current lang setting is stored in the elements.lang attribute. This is stated in the documentation, but we missed it. So **the implicit lang parameter should not be used in the field template**, because it contains wrong value.

The solution was this: @elements.errors(**elements.lang**)

```
    @elements.input
    <span class="errors">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
```